# PHP variables in dynamic CSS

Tags: php, mysql, css, variables, dynamic

I'm using a PHP/MySQL to style a web app using dynamic css (style.php).

The MySQL values are determined from the URL:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($url == "this") $style = "blue";
else( $style = "red"; )
```

The problem I seem to be having is that the style.php uses:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

This causes $url to be equal to: "http://", also any other variables assigned outside of the style.php file are ignored.

Does anyone know how to get these $_SERVER (and other) variables to work?

Here is the full code

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // current URL

$key = true;

while($key){

mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
$query_rsTheme = "
SELECT      s.name, s.url, t.name as theme, t.colour, t.hover 
FROM        db_site as s
INNER JOIN  db_theme.theme as t ON t.name = s.theme
WHERE       s.url = '$url'";
$rsTheme = mysql_query($query_rsTheme, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsTheme = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTheme);
$totalRows_rsTheme = mysql_num_rows($rsTheme);

if($totalRows_rsTheme == 1){ // sucessful match
    $key = false;

    $site = $row_rsTheme['name'];
    $theme = $row_rsTheme['theme'];
    $default_state = $row_rsTheme['colour'];
    $hover_state = $row_rsTheme['hover'];
}

$tokens = explode('/', $url);
$remove = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2]."/";
$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, $remove));
}

header('Content-type: text/css');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

$stylesheet = 'style.css';

$content = preg_replace('/\$([\w]+)/e','$0',@file_get_contents($stylesheet));

echo $content;
```

Comment: How is style.php invoked?

Comment: what is purpose of style.php?

Comment: if($url == "this"){ $style = "blue";} else { $style = "red";}

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/version-3/css/style.php" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>

Comment: I can't understand what your problem is but I can assure you that the `header()` function does not write anything in the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: style.php should determine what the url is, query a MySQL table to find the 'theme', producing hex colour values. style.php then echos style.css, which then displays the hex colours.

Comment: header is not writing anything to the $_SERVER array, this is not the problem. My problem is, for some reason the $_SERVER array is empty within style.php

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU The point of style.php is http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: why do u make an infinite loop?

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: it's not an infinite loop, as there will always be at least one result in the database, depending on what the url is. The problem is, the $_SEVER array is empty within the style.php file.

Comment: @Vector..thank you for responsive me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention several times that `$_SERVER` is empty but I suspect you don't really test it:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Whatever, your `style.php` script assumes that certain global variables exist (namely `$database` and `$connection`). If you've really posted the complete script, you never define them.

You also mention:

> any other variables assigned outside of the style.php file are ignored.

Of course. That's how PHP works: each script is independent. Thankfully, `style.php` will not pick variables from any other random script that runs on the same server.

My advice is:

1. Enable full error reporting. It's clear that you aren't seeing notices and possibly warnings and errors.
2. Test the script separately. Load `http://example.com/include/version-3/css/style.php` in your browser and see the generated code, rather than possibly relying on styles showing up in your HTML.

Comment: problem found: style.php is being accessed through http://, so the server variables were being set, i was calling the $url variable at a later stage where the $tokens were being removed. I added a landing page parameter to style.php?page=$currentPage; which solves my problem. sorry for the confusion.#]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not what you're describing. So long as `style.php` is accessed via http, then the `$_SERVER` variables *will* be set.

There *is*, however, some syntax error in the code you described:

```
if($url == "this") $style = "blue";
else( $style = "red"; )  // Incorrect syntax
```

The right way to write that would be:

```
if ($url == "this") { // $url will _never_ be "this"
    $style = "blue";
} else {
    $style = "red";
}
```

**Edit:** There's some funky code when evaluating the MySQL results:

```
$row_rsTheme = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTheme);
$totalRows_rsTheme = mysql_num_rows($rsTheme);

if($totalRows_rsTheme == 1){ // sucessful match, but ONLY if there's only one row
    ...
}
```

You should replace it with:

```
if($row_rsTheme = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTheme)){ // sucessful match
    ...
}
```

That way, there will be success even if there's more than one result.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the URI matches certain characters

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'this') !== FALSE ){
    $style = "blue";
} else {
    $style = "red";
}
```

This is particularly helpful if the file you are using is in fact an include into another file.